# Accessing variables outside of function: JavaScript

Tags: javascript

From what I've read, I have to set a global `var` outside of a the functions, in order to use it elsewhere.

However, this just isn't working for me.  I am working inside of a Chrome extension, but I don't see how that could affect anything.

```
var value;

function getCookies(domain, name) {
    chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
        value = cookie.value;
    });
}

function run() {
    getCookies("http://myurl.com", "cookiename");
    console.log(value);
}

run();
```

In console, the "value" is undefined, and I have no idea why.  If I print the value out inside of getCookies, it shows me the correct value, so that's working.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Because of asynchronicity. The code below getCookies is called befor the callback is executed.

Comment: chrome.cookies.get is asynchronous?

Comment: It's so tempting to answer when it would take 10 times less time than looking for the proper duplicate.

Comment: There is so many duplicates around.